# Is the transformation $T$ orthogonally diagonalisable?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Let $T: P_3 \rightarrow P_3$ be the transformation $T(f)=5 \operatorname{proj}_v(f) -2f$ where $V$ is a subspace spanned by the vectors $1 + 2t+t^2$ and $t +t^2+ 3t^3$.

The inner product on the vector space $P_{3}$ is defined as:  $\textit{f} \cdot \textit{g} =\int_{-1}^1 fg \,dt$

a) determine a matrix representation (D) for the transofmration S relative to a basis $\beta$ of eigenvalues

b) is the transformation $T$ orthogonally diagonalisable?

I solved a) by choosing a basis $\beta=\{f_1, f_2, g_1, g_2\}$ where $f_1, f_2$ form a basis for $V$ and $g_1, g_2$ form a basis for the orthogonal complement of $V.$ However, I don't know how to reason on b). The solution says that it is orthogonally diagonalisable because you can choose a ON-basis for $V$ and an ON-basis for the orthogonal complement of $V$, thus forming an ON-basis of eigenvectors for $P_3$.

How do I know that I can form an ON-basis for the two subspaces and why is that sufficent to show that $T$ is orthogonally diagonalisable? Can't an ON basis be formed for all subspaces using the Gram-Schmidt process, thus you can find an ON-basis for all eigenspaces, which then would imply that all matrices are orthogonally diagonalisable which is not the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The answer to a) is
$$D= \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Which inner product are you using on $P_3$? Without that information, the problem, talking about “orthogonally diagonalisable” makes no sense.

Comment: right, sorry. I edited in the definition of the inner product now!

Comment: Note that $T = 5P-2I$ is symmetric and hence orthogonally diagonalizable.

Comment: Thank you! How can you see that the transformation is symmetric? And if I is the identity matrix, where did it come from? I know about symmetric matrices, but I don't have the matrix A for the transformation

Answer (score 1):

If you apply Gramm-Schmidt to $\{f_1,f_2\}$, you will get a set $\{h_1,h_2\}$ of two orthonormal elements of $V$. Besides, $T(h_1)=3h_1$ and $T(h_2)=3h_2$. And if you apply Gramm-Schmidt to $\{g_1,g_2\}$, you will get a set $\{h_3,h_4\}$ of other two orthonormal elements of $V$. Besides, $T(h_3)=-2h_3$, $T(h_4)=-2h_4$, and, since $h_1,h_2\in V$ and $h_3,h_4\in V^\perp$, the set $\{h_1,h_2,h_3,h_4\}$ is also orthonormal. Finaly, the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $\{h_1,h_2,h_3,h_4\}$ as the one that you got.

Comment: Thank you. Why is showing that there is an ON-basis for P_{3} is enough to show that the transformation is orthogonally diagonalisable? As obtaining an orthonormal basis is possible for all subspaces, how does it distinguish when a matris A is merely diagonalisable and orthogonally diagonalisable

Comment: For instance, the linear map $T\colon\Bbb R^2\longrightarrow\Bbb R^2$ defined by $T(x,y)=(x-y,0)$ is diagonalisable, since $T(1,0)=1\times(1,0)$, and $T(1,1)=0\times(1,1)$. But it is not orthogonally diagonalisable, since it has no orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.